# Finding means from fields in a structure without for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, structure, mean

I have data from an experiment in a structure like this:

```
data.subject.trial
```

I need to find the means for scores on trials across all participants (e.g. what is the mean score of all participants on trial x?).

I can get there using a for loop as below but it feels like there should be an easier one-liner to achieve the same thing (values in "trial" are numeric in this instance). Any tips? Many thanks!

```
for i = 1:length(data.subject)
    for j = 1:length(data.subject(i).trial)
        a(i,j) = data.subject(i).trial(j);
    end
end
trialMeans = mean(a);
```

Comment: Per [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-structure-array.html): "Note:   You can index into part of a field only when you refer to a single element of a structure array. MATLAB® does not support statements such as `S(1:2).X(1:50,1:80)`, which attempt to index into a field for multiple elements of the structure."

Comment: you are basically doing the mean of all trials in all subjects, so you should just use `cell2mat(struct2cell(data.subject))` and then take the column of the trails and then run the mean?

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thanks for this but it doesn't quite work with my data - I have additional subfields with different data types so it throws up an error. The best solution I've found which is similar is      `A = cell2mat({data.subject.trial});    % Put all scores from all trials into 1 vector
B = reshape(A,[],length(data.subject))';          % Reshape into rows of however many subjects`

Comment: ah, good one, I think you should answer the question yourself - the problem is we don't see what the exact data looks like, so we are hesitant to provide an answer. Just remember to post a small chunk of what the data look next time :)

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thanks, I've added an answer. Thanks too for the (gentle!) pointer for next time.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've stumbled across an answer to my own question...

```
A = cell2mat({data.subject.trial}); % Put all scores from all trials into 1 vector 
B = reshape(A,[],length(data.subject))'; % Reshape into rows of however many subjects there are
trialMeans = mean(B);
```

Thanks!